# Delete Folder in DBFS

Tags: linux, apache-spark, databricks

I want to delete all the folders from my path

```
dbfs:/databricks-results/
```

When I try :

```
dbutils.fs.rm('dbfs:/databricks-results/', True)
```

I get SQL Parse Exception

How do I solve this

Comment: What if you try `dbfs://` with two `/` ?

Comment: it will fail because `://` is used when you have host name, and this is not a case for DBFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your notebook has SQL as primary language, but you're trying to use the Python code.  Change your cell to:

```
%python
dbutils.fs.rm('dbfs:/databricks-results/', True)
```

P.S. You can omit `dbfs:` - it's used by default.